# addChild does not work inside function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm having a problem with using addChild in my program, the document class goes as such:

```
public function gridtest()
    {
        turn++;
        var plusX = 1;
        var plusY = 0;

        trace ("game started");

        var i;
        var j;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            trace ("first for loop");

            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                gridbutton = new GridButton();

                gridbutton.x += plusX;
                gridbutton.y += plusY;
                gridbutton.GBID = (i*10)+ j;

                trace ("created button at " + plusX + "," + plusY);

                addChild(gridbutton);
                GBList.push(gridbutton);
                trace("grid button number " + i + j + " added");
                plusX += 92.5;
            }

            plusY += 61.5;
            plusX = 1;
        }
    }
```

I have one addChild in the main function gridtest(), which works fine, but the other one in the second function here (still the same document):

```
            static function NewUnit(locX, locY)
    {
    unit = new Unit(locX, locY);
    unit.Set_ID(UnitList.length);
    addChild(unit);
    UnitList.push(Unit);
    }
```

gives me the error 1180:Call to a possibly undefined method addChild, does it have something to do with the function being static? Or is it something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[addChild](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/common/langref/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29) is a non-static function. Interaction between static and non-static functions is unavailable. you should refer to an instance of Object first and call the function from that instance. Please check `trace(this);` in static function.

If you want object addChild. should add an additional parameter for the parent you want to add to.

```
static function NewUnit(locX:Number, locY:Number, parent:DisplayObjectContainer)
{
    unit = new Unit(locX, locY);
    unit.Set_ID(UnitList.length);
    parent.addChild(unit);
    UnitList.push(Unit);
}
```